# Can we classify all topological space $(X, \tau) $ where every second category sets are Residual sets?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, descriptive-set-theory, baire-category, the-baire-space

$(X, \tau) $ be a topological space.

> $A\subset X$ is Residual if $X\setminus A$ is of first category.

In a Baire space, a Residual set is of second category.

> $A\subset X$ Residual, then $X\setminus A$ is of first category.

And every Baire space is of second category in itself implies $A$ is of second category.

Hence, in a Baire space $ (X, \tau) $ every Residual set is of second category.

My Question :

1. In a topological space $(X, \tau) $ every Residual set is of second category. Does this imply $(X, \tau) $ is a Baire space?
2. Can we classify all topological space $(X, \tau) $ where every second category sets are Residual sets?

Comment: 1. No, $\Bbb Q\sqcup\Bbb R$ has the property that every residual set is of second category, but it is not Baire

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ is a space as in 2. because all subsets are first category and so all subsets are residual. Beware of such "extreme" cases. There are no second category subsets so the condition is void.